# Consulta con condiciones operando con ALIAS en SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, select

Teniendo en cuanta que A y C son subquerys... que representan los  articulos asiganados y los articulos contados

```
COUNT(OSZE.X_OrgSubZonaElem_ID) CANT_ELEMENTOS,
COUNT (A.X_OrgSubZonaElem_ID) CANT_ASIG,
COUNT (C.X_OrgSubZonaElem_ID) CANT_CONT,


     CASE WHEN CANT_ELEMENTOS != 0 AND CANT_ELEMENTOS IS NOT NULL AND CANT_CONT != 0 AND CANT_CONT IS NOT NULL 
     THEN (CANT_CONT*100)/CANT_ELEMENTOS ELSE 0 END AS PCTJ_AVANCE, 

     SUM (CANT_ELEMENTOS) AS TOTAL_ELEMENT,

     SUM (CANT_CONT) AS TOTAL_COUNTED,

     CASE WHEN TOTAL_ELEMENT !=0 AND TOTAL_ELEMENT IS NOT NULL  AND TOTAL_COUNTED IS NOT NULL AND TOTAL_COUNTED !=0 
     THEN (TOTAL_COUNTED*100)/TOTAL_ELEMENT   ELSE 0 END AS TOTAL_AVANCE
```

¿Es valido usar un ALIAS para operar?  -- me esta marcando error : empieza en en el CASE WHEN CANT_ELEMENTOS dice que la variable global CANT_ELEMENTOS no se encuentra

Respondiendo a los comentarios.. tambien debo sacar los totales, serian: SUM(C.CampoElemento_ID) AS TOTAL_CONT y SUM(A.CampoElemento_ID) AS TOTAL_ASIG cierto? Ya vi que no, porque es un ID y no puedo sumar sus ID da un numero bestial... y no puedo hacer un SUM(COUNT)  :( ¿como hago?

Comment: que error te esta marcando? donde?

Comment: empieza en en el CASE WHEN CANT_ELEMENTOS dice que la variable global CANT_ELEMENTOS no puede ser encontrada.

Comment: ok. ese error es el que tiene que estar escrito en la pregunta. usa el boton [edit] y agregalo. y no, ya entendi tu problema, y no, no lo podes hacer asi, tenes que escribir el count de vuelta ahi adentro.

Answer (score 1):

Iría mas o menos así..

Ah! y los SUM te redundan son prácticamente lo mismo que tienes arriba... solo que le pusiste otro nombre me imagino que para operar. Pero no se puede operar con ALIS del MISMO NIVEL. Tendrian que se desde otra subconsulta o de esta manera:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(OSZE.CampoElemento_ID) != 0 AND COUNT(OSZE.CampoElemento_ID) IS NOT NULL 
    AND COUNT (C.CampoElemento_ID) != 0 AND COUNT (C.CampoElemento_ID) IS NOT NULL 
    THEN (COUNT (C.CampoElemento_ID)*100)/COUNT(OSZE.CampoElemento_ID) ELSE 0 
    END AS PCTJ_AVANCE,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(OSZE.CampoElemento_ID) IS NOT NULL AND COUNT(OSZE.CampoElemento_ID) !=0
    AND COUNT (C.CampoElemento_ID) IS NOT NULL AND COUNT (C.CampoElemento_ID) !=0 
    THEN (COUNT (C.CampoElemento_ID)*100)/COUNT(OSZE.CampoElemento_ID)  ELSE 0 
    END AS TOTAL_AVANCE
```

(si me equivoco por favor corrijan mi falla, acepto criticas. )

Comment: amigo gracias por tu respuesta, pero te corrijo que los SUM no redundan.. porque cada uno se supone debe crear una nueva columna que tenga los totales... ya que una cosa es los Artículos Asignados y otra cosa es el Total de artículos Asignados en TODO el proceso...

Comment: Usando tu respuesta y lo que haz comentado lo que deberia para sacar los totales serian: SUM(C.CampoElemento_ID) AS TOTAL_CONT y SUM(A.CampoElemento_ID) AS TOTAL_ASIG cierto?